# why this deconstructuring return array's length?

Tags: javascript, arrays, curly-braces, square-bracket, destructure

I can't find description about this code in JS...

```
    let arr = [3, 1, 5, 1, 2, 1, 1];

    let { length } = arr;

    console.log(length);
```

why this code work like arr.length and how should I call it?

Comment: That's... just how destructing works. `let { length } = arr;` is equivalent to `let length = arr.length;`. It extracts the `length` property of the object and puts it into a variable named `length`

Comment: @CertainPerformance thx for your answer. Could I ask you two more questions??? 
First, is it possible to check what kind of properties are included?? 
And... does array object has only one instance property "length"??

Comment: You can iterate over own properties of an object with `Object.keys` or `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` depending on whether you care about enumerability. The array has other instance properties too - the array indicies, like `1` and `2`